# Serving an image from PIL dynamically

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, paste

I am using PIL (Python Imaging Library), and Paste to make a very simple web page. I have a function that returns just an image tag:

```
def home(self):
    return '<img src="photo" alt="photo"/>'
```

And I also have a function called photo that (ideally) returns the image to be put in the img tag:

```
def photo(self):
    img = image_from_PIL # this part works
    output = StringIO.StringIO()
    img.save(output, "JPEG") # saves the image as a StringIO in output
    final_img = output.getvalue()
    output.close()

    # then set headers['content-type'] = 'image/jpeg' (confirmed this works)

    return [final_img]
```

So I know that the image exists in the string `final_img` and that the content-type is "image/jpeg". I'd expect this to work, but all I get is a 200 status OK reponse of size 0.

I tried many other things too including:

- Converting the string to binary and spitting that out
- Setting the content-length in the header to the length of the string (and x8 since each char is 8 bits)

If it makes any difference, my server is using uWSGI and nginx

I don't know what else to try! Thanks for any help.

Comment: Why do you return a list with element final_img and not final_img itself?

Comment: So I can't answer my own question yet, but WOW thanks so much Hyperboreus. That worked! The reason why it was in a list was because that's how strings are returned in all of the WSGI examples I saw. For some reason, this worked.

Comment: I posted an answer saying the same thing as my comment, so you can close this question. Glad to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not return a list with the image, but the image itself.

Replace

```
return [final_img]
```

with

```
return final_img
```